# Print the path comprised by the nodes corresponding to the Diameter of a BST

Tags: c++, c, binary-search-tree

I know how to find the diameter of a BST.

```
int diameter(struct node * tree)
{

if (tree == 0)
 return 0;


int lheight = height(tree->left);
int rheight = height(tree->right);

int ldiameter = diameter(tree->left);
int rdiameter = diameter(tree->right);

return max(lheight + rheight + 1, max(ldiameter, rdiameter));
}




int height(struct node* node)
{

if(node == NULL)
   return 0;


return 1 + max(height(node->left), height(node->right));
}
```

What changes should i make in the code to print the path i.e the nodes corresponding to the diameter of the tree in a sequence from one leaf node to the other leaf node of the diameter.

For example:-

```
                     8
                   /  \
                  1    12
                  \     /
                   5   9
                 /   \
                4     7
                     /
                    6
```

output should be  6 7 5 1 8 12 9

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does one define the *diameter* of a binary tree? (Do they have *diameters*?)

Comment: @Thomas Matthews 
(http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/5687) to know more abt diameter of BST

Answer (score 3):

Here's an algorithm for finding the maximum **depth** of a binary tree:

1. Let there be a varible called `max_height`.
2. Initialize to zero.
3. Let there be a variable called `depth`.
4. Initialize `depth` to zero.
5. When traversing to a subtree, increment `depth`.
6. If `depth` is greater than `max_height`, set `max_height` to
   `depth`.
7. When returning from a subtree, decrement `depth`.

This assumes the reader knows how to traverse a binary tree; which is a topic for another post.

Comment: I know how to find the Maxdepth of a binary tree
what i need to do is print thePrint the path comprised by the nodes corresponding to the Diameter of a BST

Comment: I know how to find MaxDepth of a binary tree,I wanted to Print the path comprised by the nodes corresponding to the Diameter of a BST.
The path which comprises MaxDepth, some nodes on this Maxdepth Path will be a part of Diamter of a tree.

From diameter of a tree , i can find out the center of the diameter which will be at (D-floor(M/2)) distance away from the root on the maxDepth path, where D- no. of nodes on MaxDepth path, M- Diameter of the tree.

Comment: Can you print the nodes when you determine the diameter: geeksforgeeks.org/archives/5687

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node
{    
node* left,right;
int data;
};
struct path
{
node *nodepointer;
int length;
};
int flag=0;

node *x,*y,*lca;

path *printpath(node *leaf,int d)
{
if(flag==0)
{
    path *dia= new path;
    dia->length=0;
    dia->nodepointer=NULL;

    if(leaf==NULL)
    return dia;

    path *a=new path;
    path *b=new path;
    a=printpath(leaf->left,d);
    b=printpath(leaf->right,d);


    if(a->length + b->length + 1 == d )
    {
        lca=leaf;
        x=a->nodepointer;
        y=b->nodepointer;
        flag=1;
    }

    dia->length=max(a->length,b->length)+1;

    if(a->length > b->length && a->nodepointer!=NULL)
    {
        dia->nodepointer=a->nodepointer;
    }
    if(b->length >= a->length && b->nodepointer!=NULL)
    {
        dia->nodepointer=b->nodepointer;
    }
    if(a->nodepointer==NULL && b->nodepointer==NULL)
    {
            dia->nodepointer=leaf;
    }

    return dia;

}

}
```

Comment: What is "d" when you initially call the function?

Comment: d is the diameter of the tree. This is the code which finds out the common ancestor of the leaf nodes ,of the diameter of a BST